# what are the best ways to make animations in android?

Tags: android, jquery, animation

I know the basics of android and want to make some animations and something like games how do I do it.
If I want to put some animation in a application what would be the best way to do it is there any good tutorials on it?

If I want to do it is it possible to do it with jQuery?

Mainly I want to make games and add little animations with my applications.
so I need a place to start.can you please help me to get a better tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For animation create folder anim and push xml animation files. For game start learning engine and box 2d, also learn surface view